# Group by type and sum the quantity in crystal reports vb.net

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have a crystal reports. In my reports there is a column for type of car and quantity.

I want to group it by Type of card and the quantity will be added together

For example

```
1. type 1.....10
2. type 2.....20
3. type 1.....5
```

when it is group in crystal report

it will be

```
1. type 1....15
2. type 2....20
```

How can I do this? 
I tried adding a `running total field` but there is no **"Sum"** in my type of summary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Insert group for Car Type.
2. Drag and put Quantity field in Details section.
3. Right click the Quantity in Details section and then select "Insert" option, followed by "Summary" option.
4. If Quantity field is string type then please change the field type. You may define a Formula field to convert it to decimal. Then add this new field to detailed section.
5. In summary window you can select "Sum".
6. You may suppress all the sections except Group or as the case may be.

See the screen shot.
[image]

Comment: tried this but it only give me total sum of Quantity at the bottom

Comment: I hope you have selected summary location to group car type (as shown in image). If not you can edit this field("sum of Quantity") or redo. If you want sum along with group header, you can drag this "sum of Quantity" to group header from Group footer.